# Creating comma delimited array of floating point numbers and naming the array after first element (string) of the line in a CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv, file-io

[image]

I am trying to read in lines from the **csv** file, opened above in excel, using python for use in my python script. I would like to take each row and create an array corresponding to this row which is named by the element in the first column and the array itself would be the elements to the right. So for the first line of the csv I want to create an array

```
Line_1i = ([0.207161, 0.266311, 0.972088, 0.839942, 0.96135, 0.074271, 0.000249])
```

Now I have tried to use the following Python code:

```
with open(filename) as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
         for row in reader:
              str(row[0]) = row[1:]
```

but this does not work. Various alterations of the last line have not worked either and I am now unsure as to how to name the array of the values by the corresponding name in the first column of the row.

Whilst googling online I can find many problems and solutions that are quite close to my problem but none which takes the first element of the row and uses it to name an array of the values in that row. I feel this could be quite a common issue.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Where do you think you are creating the array?

Comment: Yes, it's a common issue, and the standard solution is to use a dictionary. It's _possible_ to dynamically create variable names in Python, but it's _really_ not a good idea. How were you intending to access those dynamically-named lists?

Comment: @PM2Ring I have another function in my script which takes two arrays (i think numpy arrays) as its arguments. Therefore I need to be able to read in the rows, save them in the python script, then later access them by name when calling the later function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables don't work like that, you can't give them dynamic names. Use a dictionary with string keys:

```
result = {}

with ... for ...
    result[row[0]] = row[1:]

print(result['Line_1i'])  # prints [0.207161, 0.266311, ...]
```

Comment: OK great. How would you be able to get rid of the NaNs created by the csv reader in this method? Its quite important that the arrays will be of differing size/length.

Comment: @Jurassic if you're not using pandas you shouldn't be getting NaNs. In any case this sounds like a fresh question which should include some code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use dictionary. Something :

```
your_dict= {}
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        your_dict[str(row[0])] = row[1:]
```

Normally it should work!

Comment: There's no need for the `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically require this loop based solution, the easiest thing will probably be to do:

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)
```

This will parse the files into a table like format for you, with `NaN` where values are missing (as per your screenshot).

Comment: Don't expect a beginner who doesn't understand how variables work to use dataframes.

Comment: I had tried to use dataframes myself actually but i still need each row as an array to pass as an argument to a function later in my python script. I could not work out how to do this in the format as described above